# How to I create a boost multiarray of a specific class?

Tags: c++, class, boost, multidimensional-array, insert

This is my first time using Boost and I am trying to create a multiarray of the class Blocks, which is stored inside the class Chunk. So each Chunk is composed of ( BLOCKS_PER_CHUNK x BLOCKS_PER_CHUNK x BLOCKS_PER_CHUNK ) number of Blocks, essentially the same way as Minecraft does. At the moment I am trying to initialize this array using two different constructors, one which takes an stl vector as an input and another that utilizes a "C style vector".

Block only has a Boolean to check if it is active (default value is false), a block type (basically an enum) and a getter and setter for the variables.

The header for Chunk is as follows:

```
#pragma once

#include "Block.h"
#include <vector>
#include "Block.h"
#include "boost/multi_array.hpp" // Multi dimensional array

#define BLOCKS_PER_CHUNK 16

class Chunk
{
public:
    Chunk();
    Chunk(std::vector<Block>& blocks);
    Chunk(Block* blocks); // Assumes you have a vector of the correct size
    virtual ~Chunk();

    void Update(float timeSinceLastUpdate);

private:
    //BlockVec3D blocks;
    //BlockArray blocks;
    typedef boost::multi_array<Block, BLOCKS_PER_CHUNK> blockArray;
    typedef blockArray::index blockArrayIndex;

    blockArray m_blocks;
};
```

The problem functions are below:

```
Chunk::Chunk(std::vector<Block>& blocks):
    m_blocks(boost::extents[BLOCKS_PER_CHUNK][BLOCKS_PER_CHUNK][BLOCKS_PER_CHUNK])
{
    assert(blocks.size() == BLOCKS_PER_CHUNK * BLOCKS_PER_CHUNK * BLOCKS_PER_CHUNK && "Number of blocks and size of the chunk do not match");
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < BLOCKS_PER_CHUNK; ++i)
    {
        for(unsigned j = 0; j < BLOCKS_PER_CHUNK; ++j)
        {
            for( unsigned k = 0; k < BLOCKS_PER_CHUNK; ++k)
            {
                m_blocks[i][j][k] = blocks[i + BLOCKS_PER_CHUNK * (j + BLOCKS_PER_CHUNK * k) ];
            }
        }
    }
}

Chunk::Chunk(Block* blocks)
{
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < BLOCKS_PER_CHUNK; ++i)
    {
        for(unsigned j = 0; j < BLOCKS_PER_CHUNK; ++j)
        {
            for( unsigned k = 0; k < BLOCKS_PER_CHUNK; ++k)
            {
                m_blocks[i][j][k] = blocks[i + BLOCKS_PER_CHUNK * (j + BLOCKS_PER_CHUNK * k) ];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Upon attempting to compile this code, I receive error such as shape, num_dimensions, begin and end not being members of Block. It seems boost has its own flavor of static assert, one that checks for required fields , when these are not found, it creates a compilation error. Apparently, boost is trying to treat the input values as one dimensional subarrays and when it fails to find the required fields for its sanity checks (such as both "subarrays" possessing the same number of dimensions), it triggers the error.

The manuals for the container do not seem to address this specific problem and I do not believe that I am accidentaly creating a multiarray view. In addition, casting the indices on the left side into 
`boost::multi_array<Block, BLOCKS_PER_CHUNK>::index` does not seem to produce any difference. As I mentioned, I am still very new to boost. What would be the correct method for doing this ?

Answer (score 0):

Error is in the way m_blocks is initialized. You specify BLOCKS_PER_CHUNK value as 16 but only initialize it as 3 dimension array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/multi_array.hpp>
#include <cassert>

#define BLOCKS_PER_CHUNK 3

struct Block{


};


struct Chunk{


  typedef boost::multi_array<Block, BLOCKS_PER_CHUNK> array_type;
  typedef array_type::index index;
  array_type m_blocks;

  Chunk(std::vector<Block>& blocks):
    m_blocks(boost::extents[BLOCKS_PER_CHUNK][BLOCKS_PER_CHUNK][BLOCKS_PER_CHUNK])
  {
    assert(blocks.size() == BLOCKS_PER_CHUNK * BLOCKS_PER_CHUNK * BLOCKS_PER_CHUNK && "Number of   
blocks and size of the chunk do not match");
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < BLOCKS_PER_CHUNK; ++i)
    {
      for(unsigned j = 0; j < BLOCKS_PER_CHUNK; ++j)
      {
for( unsigned k = 0; k < BLOCKS_PER_CHUNK; ++k)
        {
          m_blocks[i][j][k] = blocks[i + BLOCKS_PER_CHUNK * (j + BLOCKS_PER_CHUNK * k) ];
        }
      }
    }
  }

  Chunk(Block* blocks)
  {
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < BLOCKS_PER_CHUNK; ++i)
    {
      for(unsigned j = 0; j < BLOCKS_PER_CHUNK; ++j)
      {
        for( unsigned k = 0; k < BLOCKS_PER_CHUNK; ++k)
        {
          m_blocks[i][j][k] = blocks[i + BLOCKS_PER_CHUNK * (j + BLOCKS_PER_CHUNK * k) ];
        }
      }
    }
  }

};

int main(){
 return 0;
}
```

Example above compiles correctly because BLOCKS_PER_CHUNK and m_blocks initialize match. Say for example BLOCKS_PER_CHUNK is defined as 4 then m_blocks should be initialized as:

```
  #define BLOCKS_PER_CHUNK 4

struct Block{


};


struct Chunk{

  typedef boost::multi_array<Block, BLOCKS_PER_CHUNK> array_type;
  typedef array_type::index index;
  array_type m_blocks;

  Chunk(std::vector<Block>& blocks):
//initialization has to change if BLOCKS_PER_CHUNK changes
    m_blocks(
boost::extents[BLOCKS_PER_CHUNK][BLOCKS_PER_CHUNK][BLOCKS_PER_CHUNK][BLOCKS_PER_CHUNK])
  {

    assert(blocks.size() == BLOCKS_PER_CHUNK * BLOCKS_PER_CHUNK * BLOCKS_PER_CHUNK && "Number of   blocks and size of the chunk do not match");
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < BLOCKS_PER_CHUNK; ++i)
    {
      for(unsigned j = 0; j < BLOCKS_PER_CHUNK; ++j)
      {
        for( unsigned k = 0; k < BLOCKS_PER_CHUNK; ++k)
        {
//correct value assignment has to be taken care when BLOCKS_PER_CHUNK change
          m_blocks[i][j][k][k] = blocks[i + BLOCKS_PER_CHUNK * (j + BLOCKS_PER_CHUNK * k) ];
        }
      }
    }
  }

};
```

If you want 16 wide, 16 tall and 16 deep collection of blocks then code should be like this:

```
  #define BLOCKS_PER_CHUNK 16
  #define DIMENSION 3

struct Block{


};


struct Chunk{

typedef boost::multi_array<Block, DIMENSION> array_type;
  typedef array_type::index index;
  array_type m_blocks;

  Chunk(std::vector<Block>& blocks):
//initialization has to change if BLOCKS_PER_CHUNK changes
    m_blocks(
boost::extents[BLOCKS_PER_CHUNK][BLOCKS_PER_CHUNK][BLOCKS_PER_CHUNK])
  {

    assert(blocks.size() == BLOCKS_PER_CHUNK * BLOCKS_PER_CHUNK * BLOCKS_PER_CHUNK && "Number of   blocks and size of the chunk do not match");
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < BLOCKS_PER_CHUNK; ++i)
    {
      for(unsigned j = 0; j < BLOCKS_PER_CHUNK; ++j)
      {
        for( unsigned k = 0; k < BLOCKS_PER_CHUNK; ++k)
        {
//correct value assignment has to be taken care when BLOCKS_PER_CHUNK change
          m_blocks[i][j][k] = blocks[i + BLOCKS_PER_CHUNK * (j + BLOCKS_PER_CHUNK * k) ];
        }
      }
    }
  }

};
```

The second parameter in the array_type typedef specifies the dimension of array, in your case you want it to be 3 then typedef should be modified to:

```
typedef boost::multi_array<Block, DIMENSION> array_type; //where DIMENSION is 3
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I have at the moment. No other compilation errors are present. However, I think both of your constructors are equal to mine. Does that mean that syntax should be correct ? Could it be my IDE then ? Currently using Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: Can u add more info regarding your Structure Block?

Comment: Block only has a Boolean to check if it is active (default value is false), a block type (basically an enum) and a getter and setter for the variables.

Comment: I don't see an issue in that, you should provide a Short, Self Contained, Correct Example. Also please provide the exact compiler error.

Comment: Just edited in more information. The errors I obtain are that "shape", "num_dimensions", "equal", "begin" and "end" are not members of Block. These are all triggered by BOOST_ASSERT.

Comment: Not quite sure I understand, if BLOCKS_PER_CHUNK is 16, that means I want a 16 wide, 16 tall, 16 deep collection of blocks, not a 16 dimensional matrix. How would I have to change it to accomplish that ?

Comment: @BrunoAyllon if you want it to be 3 dimension and blocks per chunk to be 16 then you should correct the typedef for array, check the modified answer. Understand how array is declared.